# I can't add data in to variable. Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net

Here I am trying to get the user which logged on the login page but I don't understand why _id, name and class can't get any data in the method.

```cs
public class Login
{
    SQLiteConnection _sqlconnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteConnection>().GetConnection();
    SQLiteManager manager;
    public static int _id;
    public static string _name;
    public static string _class;

    public void LoginMethod()
    {
        string name = LoginPage.Name;
        string password = LoginPage.Password;
        string getId = "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Name='" + name +"' AND Password='" + password + "'";
        var Id = _sqlconnection.CreateCommand(getId);
        var id = Id.ExecuteScalar<int>();
        var profileUser = manager.Get6(id);
        _id = profileUser.Id;
        _name = profileUser.Name;
        _class = profileUser.Class;
    }        
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. It's just doesn't work. When I add a data into the variable in here: public static int _id;
        public static string _name;
        public static string _class;   it is working but when I add a data in the function It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms? What package for SQlite are you using?

Comment: Yes I use SQLite.NET-PCL package

Comment: So when you add a breakpoint to the end of your LoginMethod, profileUser.Id, profileUser.Name, and profileUser.Class do contain values right ?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger to step through your code and verify the execution?

Comment: Do you have data in the database?

Comment: Yes I have data to get.